# Deleting other drawings while cleaning a canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make an application with canvas. But I need to delete a drawing I created in my application. I want the red to stay steady and the blue to reflect as I hold it down. But while cleaning the canvas, the previous blue drawings are also gone. How should I go about deleting a drawing? I also tried throwing it into an array and deleting it with remove() but it didn't work. If I delete it with its coordinates, all the drawings in those coordinates will also disappear.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-pl-c-canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

class Player {

    constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    top() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
    }
    update(nx, ny) {
       
        this.x = nx;
        this.y = ny;
    }
}
const x = canvas.width / 2;
const y = canvas.height / 2;

var player = new Player(x, y, 30,'red');
player.top();


addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    player.update(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    player.top();
    if(clck == true){
        var wd = new Player(e.clientX, e.clientY, 300,'blue');
        wd.top();
    }
})

var clck=false;
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    clck=false;
})
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    clck=true;
})
```

```css
 *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #canvas-pl-c-canvas:hover{
            cursor: none;
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-pl-c-canvas"></canvas>
```

In the above snippet I'm trying to get the blue to draw without the red disappearing, but it doesn't work because the entire area is cleared with c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height). Is this the only way to clean it? How can I delete one of two overlapping drawings? How can I save my drawings somewhere and delete them?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-pl-c-canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
// ctx.fillStyle='blue';
// ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
class Player {

    constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    top() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
    }
    update(nx, ny) {
       
        this.x = nx;
        this.y = ny;
    }
}
const x = canvas.width / 2;
const y = canvas.height / 2;

var player = new Player(x, y, 30,'red');
player.top();


addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    // c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    player.update(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    player.top();
    if(clck == true){
        var wd = new Player(e.clientX, e.clientY, 300,'blue');
        wd.top();
    }
})

var clck=false;
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    clck=false;
})
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    clck=true;
})
```

```css
  *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #canvas-pl-c-canvas:hover{
            cursor: none;
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-pl-c-canvas"></canvas>
```

In this piece of code, I can draw blue as long as I hold it down, but it constantly writes red. I specially need to delete a drawing. I'm using completely vanilla js. I would be very grateful if you could help without suggesting a library. Thank you very much to everyone who has replied so far.

Comment: In javascript when you draw anything or clear anything in the canvas, It doesn't store anything about what was drew or removed. It handles the canvas as a static picture and drawing or deleting is just a matter of changing the pixels in that picture, what you need to do is to creat a rendering function that uses: (`setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`) and keep track of the things you are trying to render so that the rendiring function knows what to render fore each frame.

Comment: Thank you so much. requestAnimationFrame I'm investigating right now.